# git2svn unable to create symlink (File name too long)

Tags: git, svn, linux-mint, svn2git

I installed [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) to quickly convert SVN repositories to GIT. I tried the converting procedure on a different machine (Ubuntu 16.04) and a different SVN repository which worked without a problem.

Right now I am on Linux Mint Cinnamon with a different (but very simillar) SVN repository.

```
git clone https://my.git.com/repository.git
cd repository
svn2git svn://my.svn.com/repository --authors ../authors_transform.txt

.
.
.

error: unable to create symlink asp/layer/man/rep/onewith_totalmax_victory.php (File name too long)
read-tree -m -u -v HEAD HEAD: command returned error: 128
```

I have read about the /home encryption possibility (as a file length limit), which is not my case.
Tried touching random string

```
touch Etiam_tortor_est0_placerat_sit_amet_dolor_in0_ultricies_malesuada_nisi-_Aenean_et_urna_enim-_Vivamus_porta0_velit_et_pulvinar_fermentum0_urna_lacus_tempor_sapien0_et_laoreet_tellus_elit_nec_ligula-_Nulla_iaculis0_libero_eget_rutrum_mattis0_nisl_velit_vive
```

Which is 256 characters and creates the file.

How to deal with this?

**EDIT:** The problem occurs on macOS Sierra aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all it seems it has been an issue with a specific file that was symlink and a file at the same time?

Anyways manually fixing the file in SVN and then performing the conversion fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Conversion broke the symlink try this:

```
git clone --no-checkout https://my.git.com/repository.git
cd repository
git config core.symlinks false
git checkout <branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `svn2git` tool you used uses `git-svn` under the hood, so it is not suitable for "quickly convert" an SVN repository.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

The `svn2git` you used is based on `git-svn` and `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` (or the wrong `svn2git` in your case) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)